# Mac air internal keyboard and touchpad stopped working after batery replacement

Tags: mac, keyboard, battery, trackpad

Hi I have replaced my old battery with genuine one in my mac air mid 2013. After that my internal keyboard and touchpad stopped working while normal startup. I was working fine before.

What is working:

- I have run Diagnostic mode ( holding D while chime ) and there keyboard and touchpad is working properly.
- I'm also able to send commands with keyboard during startup phase, like entering verbose mode, Reseting NVRAM, entering restore mode etc. But it isn't working in safemode and even in restore mode (only when I reset NVRAM, it's working for wifi selection and when restore image boots up it not working again).

So I suppose the wire connection is solid. So I **excluded HW problem, or connection problem**.
I would suspect it's a SW problem?

Symptoms:

- Anyhow when I get to the login screen mac shows up the Bluetooth keyboard setup "There isn't a keyboard connected" dialog.
- I can connect bluetooth external keyboard and enter terminal.
- While running ioreg|grep -i keyboard. There is no sign of Internal Keyboard connected.

Solutions tried:

- I have laso tried to remove /Library/Extensions/ and also /Library/Preferences/*.plist. No difference.
- I have tried with 2 different ssd drives where I have Big Sur latest and MacOSx 10.13.5. No difference.
- SMC reset, NVRAM reset no difference.

Does anyone can help me, please?

Comment: What happens if you log in as a different user?

Comment: No, log in as different user didn't help. thanks